# Overriding GetHashCode variations

Tags: .net, vb.net, equality, gethashcode

I have a theoretical class Name_Order, that has a string `Name` and a int `Order`.

I need to indicate that two `Name_Order`'s are different, if the pair NameOrder is different, that is, or name or order are different.

Now, overriding Equals *no problemo*, but I have some "issues" with GetHashCode:

```
Public Class Name_Order
  Public Property Name As String
  Public Property Order As Integer

  Public Overrides Function Equals(ByVal obj As Object) As Boolean
    If TypeOf obj Is Name_Order Then
      Dim no = DirectCast(obj, Name_Order)
      Return Me.Name = no.Name AndAlso Me.Order = no.Order
    Else
      Return MyBase.Equals(obj)
    End If
  End Function

  Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
    Dim hcName = 0
    If Me.Name IsNot Nothing Then
      hcName = Me.Name.GetHashCode
    End If

    Dim hcOrder = Me.Order.GetHashCode

    Return hcName + hcOrder
  End Function
End Class
```

In that case, summing the hashcodes, leave a (small, but real) possibility that two distinct Name_Orders with different names or orders be "identical".

Say, adding the `7` + `154` gives the same result as adding `154` + `7`...

An alternative override of that method?

Comment: hash code collisions are unavoidable since there are only 2^32 ints but many more strings. You only can try to make collisions rare to improve performance of hash-tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, while *avoiding* collisions is good, it isn't a problem if there *are* collisions. But a common approach is something like:

```
return 7 * x.GetHashCode() + y.GetHashCode();
```

This is more noticeable in, for example, a point/position, where it would be nice to avoid obvious diagonal collisions like (2,3) vs (3,2).

A ***much*** bigger problem in your code is that the properties in the hash/equals are mutable; if they get changed, any usage in dictionaries etc will stop working. You should prefer read-only key values.

Comment: I do something similar, but use bit shifting and xor as well, as you can overflow the hashcode datatype if you are adding the hashcodes of a lot of child data fields.

Comment: @Mark Gravell: How can I use readonly properties, if I haven't...? )

Comment: @serhio in c#, either the "readonly" keyword on fields, or a "{get; private set; }" for properties. I assume VB has similar

Comment: @Marc: But I need to be able to modify that properties... I can't make it readonly...

Comment: @serhio if you modify that property *once it has been used as a key in a dictionary or similar*, then you **break** that usage. As in: can't find the item any more.

Comment: Code which adds an object (reference) to a dictionary is required to ensure that the object will not be modified in such fashion as to change its equivalence class while the dictionary holds a reference to it.  A class which overrides `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in terms of mutable properties thus places a substantial responsibility upon any code that stores it within a dictionary.  Such behavior is in a real sense dangerous, but sometimes it is in an equally-real sense necessary.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN gives its variant of the answer for that case here (in the Example's section):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx

```
Public Class Product
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Code As Integer
End Class

' Custom comparer for the Product class
Public Class ProductComparer
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Product)

    Public Function Equals1(
        ByVal x As Product, 
        ByVal y As Product
        ) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Product).Equals

        ' Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
        If x Is y Then Return True

        'Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
        If x Is Nothing OrElse y Is Nothing Then Return False

        ' Check whether the products' properties are equal.
        Return (x.Code = y.Code) AndAlso (x.Name = y.Name)
    End Function

    Public Function GetHashCode1(
        ByVal product As Product
        ) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Product).GetHashCode

        ' Check whether the object is null.
        If product Is Nothing Then Return 0

        ' Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
        Dim hashProductName = 
            If(product.Name Is Nothing, 0, product.Name.GetHashCode())

        ' Get hash code for the Code field.
        Dim hashProductCode = product.Code.GetHashCode()

        ' Calculate the hash code for the product.
        Return hashProductName Xor hashProductCode ' here.....................
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: simply `xor`ing the hash codes is usually a bad idea. In particular swapping the values of the properties will not change the hashcode. This is probably irrelevant in this case, but in many cases it is relevant.